# AWS API Gateway ignoring passthroughBehavior when proxying to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get the Gateway to reject with a 415 if Content-type is anything other than application/json when proxying to a Lambda.

I have also tried using basic swagger, but that doesn't seem to allow for rejecting based on Content-type.

```
    "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
      "type": "aws_proxy",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:${region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${post_lambda_arn}/invocations",
      "requestTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\n \"requestMethod\" : \"REQUEST\",\n \"request\" : $input.json('$') } "
      },
      "passthroughBehavior": "NEVER"
    }
```

If I tag my POST with text/plain, all validation in the gateway is bypassed, and the request is sent directly to the lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation, for proxy integrations, “API Gateway passes the entire request through to your backend and you do not have the option to modify the passthrough behaviors.”

You can read the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html).

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like I can accomplish this using a non-proxy (or custom) integration:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html